# selenium RC running on solaris error when opening firefox:symbol g_slice_set_config: referenced symbol not found

Tags: firefox, testing, selenium, solaris, selenium-rc

I am runing selenium-RC in solaris to launching web automation testing. In fact, I have used selenium in windows with no problems. And it works.
But now, I want to make automation testing on solaris server, so I start selenium RC on solaris. But when it opening a firefox, the error will come out:

```
ld.so.1: firefox-bin: fatal: relocation error: file /export/home/linus/..../firefox3.5/libxul.so: symbol g_slice_set_config: referenced symbol not found
13:11:22.400 ERROR - Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and clear all session data
java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out waiting for profile to be created!
```

But without selenium, I can open firefox in solaris with no problems. I am very confused about this problem. Does it come from selenium or firefox? Could anybody help me with this?   Thanks a lot!

P.S. I installed firefox3.5 on my solaris server. And it is in the route /export/home/linus/.....firefox3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: it seems my firefox has some problem. I install another firefox, it solved the problem.
http://opensolaris.org/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=425759